# NavigationLink inside .searchable does not work

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode13, ios15

I understand its new, but this seems like pretty basic functionality that is not here. When implementing a `.searchable` in the new iOS 15, it would seem that a NavigationLink does not work, at all.

Ideally, the searchable would produce a filtered list with a ForEach and for each item, a Nav Link could take you to another view based on your selection. The ForEach and list works and looks beautiful, it just wont take you anywhere.

Watching WWDC21, they talk an awful lot about `.searchable`, but very little demonstration/example is given..

Here is a simple example, with no ForEach loop, that shows it does not work at all.. Am I missing something?

Any insight appreciated:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var term = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
        }
        .searchable(text: $term) {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                Text("Go to second view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Goodbye!")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NavigationLink` must always be inside `NavigationView`, no matter what. If you want to put it outside, like inside `.searchable`, you should use [programmatic navigation with `isActive`](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var term = ""
    @State private var isPresenting = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            /// NavigationView must only contain 1 view
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
                
                /// invisible NavigationLink
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), isActive: $isPresenting) { EmptyView()}
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $term) {
            Button { isPresenting = true } label: {
                Text("Go to second view")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Goodbye!")
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Working navigation link that only appears when search bar tapped]

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you. So if you happen to have a large ForEach listing of choices, I guess you'd have to use Buttons to set variables based on the user's selection and then trigger the NavLink which is inside the NavView..

Comment: @Lkabo exactly. Use a list of buttons which set the NavigationLink. You'll probably need another variable to keep track of which button was pressed.

Comment: @Lkabo, please take a look at my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71312763/8068432, and see if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents using data form Apple docs.

Some notes:

1. You have to embrace list inside a NavigationView (NavigationStack for iOS17, as NavigationView is deprecated)
2. even if Apple docs (and many on web) seem say so, without Nav..XX done not work: try yourself commenting out Nav..XX

   ```
    import SwiftUI

    struct Ocean: Identifiable {
        let name: String
        let id = UUID()
    }

    struct ContentView: View {


    private var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]

    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack { // Try to commenting out.

            let filtered = self.oceans.filter { (ocean : Ocean) in
                return ocean.name.uppercased().contains(searchText.uppercased()) || searchText.isEmpty
            }
            List(filtered) { (ocean: Ocean) in
                Text(ocean.name)
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt: "")
        }
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: a little bug from Apple (iOS17??) search field capitalise initials of text.. :(