# NavigationLink doesn't work with new .searchable modifier on SwiftUI 3.0

Tags: swift, swiftui, searchable

I'm trying the new features of SwiftUI 3.0 introduced at Apple WWDC21.

In particular I'm trying to use the `.searchable` modifier to implement a search bar in a list and let the user navigate to the Item view from the search result using a `NavigationLink`.

```swift
struct OrderItem : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var label : String
    var value : Bool = false
}

struct BindingTest: View {
    @State var items = [OrderItem(label: "Shirts"), OrderItem(label: "Pants"), OrderItem(label: "Socks")]
    @State private var searchedText = ""
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List($items) { $item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: $item)) {
                    HStack {
                        if(item.value) {
                            Image(systemName: "star.fill").foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        }
                        Text(item.label)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Clothing")
            
            // Search bar
                .searchable(text: $searchedText, placement: .automatic) {
                    if searchedText != "" {
                        
                        // Search result
                        ForEach($items.filter({$0.label.wrappedValue.contains(searchedText)})) { $item in
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: $item)) {
                                HStack {
                                    if(item.value) {
                                        Image(systemName: "star.fill").foregroundColor(.yellow)
                                    }
                                    Text(item.label)
                                }
                            }.searchCompletion(item.label)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

But when I'm in the search result list and I tap on one result, the `NavigationLink` doesn't work and it shows me the original list. Anyone else experiencing this issue?

[image: I can't upload a video but this is the search result view, as I said when I tap on one result the NavigationLink doesn't work]

[EDIT]
I checked this [NavigationLink inside .searchable does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923446/navigationlink-inside-searchable-does-not-work) but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question because my `NavigationLink` is already inside a `NavigationView`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationLink inside .searchable does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923446/navigationlink-inside-searchable-does-not-work)

Comment: Unfortunately not because, as you can see in my code, the NavigationLink is already inside a NavigationView.

Comment: I'm having issues in the same vein. One, I am applying multiple filters to my ForEach. my ForEach is rendering a NavigationLink for each item in my array. The NavigationLink has a destination where I am passing a @State variable. When I tap to the next view with a filter applied, the view just sends me back to my main view and I cannot access the child view. If I remove the search and filters, then the navigation hierarchy behaves as I expect. Disappointing delivery by Apple, yet again

Answer (score 3):

You have two Navigation Links here, one inside your original content, and one passed as a closure to your searchable modifier, which is actually being shown as the searchText changes. The latter isn't inside a Navigation View, and hence is unable to navigate to the second screen. To achieve your expectation, you should have the `ForEach` with the `NavigationLink` in the original content itself, and filter the list, based on the search text.

The search completion is supposed to be a guidance to complete the searchText, not to navigate to the second screen.

The updated code should look something like this

```
struct BindingTest: View {
@State var items = [OrderItem(label: "Shirts"), OrderItem(label: "Pants"), OrderItem(label: "Socks")]
@State private var searchedText = ""

@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List($items.filter({$0.label.wrappedValue.contains(searchedText)})) { $item in
            NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: $item)) {
                HStack {
                    if(item.value) {
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill").foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    }
                    Text(item.label)
                }
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchedText, placement: .automatic) {
            if searchedText != "" {
                ForEach($items.filter({$0.label.wrappedValue.contains(searchedText)})) { $item in
                    Text(item.label).searchCompletion(item.label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Hope it answers your question :)